# Getting a segmentation fault when trying to delete a node from the list?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I am working on a delete method for a doubly linked list in which I am trying to delete some nodes after adding them to my list. Below I have provided some minimally reproducible code.

When I run this code, I receive the error `Segmentation Fault: 11`. I know that I am trying to delete the same node twice, but this should only result in an error in my code, with a message of `Invalid command\n`, but when this happens, my entire program stops and I receive the `Segmentation Fault: 11`. I believe this has something do with the `(*current)->next->prev = (*current)->prev;` in my `delete` method below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct NodeStruct Node;

//struct for each office item
struct NodeStruct {
    int id;
    struct NodeStruct *next;
    struct NodeStruct *prev; //Create doubly linked list node
};


/** Structure for the whole list, including head and tail pointers. */
typedef struct {
  /** Pointer to the first node on the list (or NULL ). */
  Node *head;
  Node *last;
} List;

List *list;

List *makeList();
void insert(int idInsert, List *list);
static void *addRecord(List *list, int newID);
static void printReverse(List *list);
void delete(int key, List *list);
bool search(List *list, int x);

int main(void) {

  //Create an empty list for you to start.
  list = (List *)makeList();

  addRecord(list, 1);
  addRecord(list, 2);
  addRecord(list, 3);
  addRecord(list, 4);
  addRecord(list, 4);
  addRecord(list, 7);
  insert(15, list);
  delete(7, list);
  delete(1, list);
  delete(4, list);
  delete(2, list);
  delete(5, list);
  delete(2, list);
  printReverse(list);

}

List *makeList()
{
  List *list = (List *) malloc( sizeof( List ) );
  list->head = NULL;
  list->last = NULL;
  return list;
}

void insert(int idInsert, List *list)
{
  //Insert the record based on the ID if no duplicates exist
  //Special case: insert at front if idInsert is less than the ID of the current head
  if (idInsert < list->head->id) {
    //Make the node with idInsert the first node
    Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node)); //Allocate memory for the new node

    list->head->prev = new;
    new->prev = NULL;
    //Add in data
    new->id = idInsert;

    new->next = list->head;

    list->head = new;
    // if the new node is the last one
  } else if (idInsert > list->last->id) {
    addRecord(list, idInsert);
    printf("RECORD INSERTED: %d\n", idInsert);
    return;
  } else { //Locate the node before the point of insertion
    //Allocate memory for the node
    Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    //Add in data
    new->id = idInsert;

    Node *current = list->head;
    while (current->next != NULL && current->next->id < new->id) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    new->next = current->next;
    if (current->next != NULL) {
      new->next->prev = new;
    }
    current->next = new;
    new->prev = current;
  }

  //Print this message if successful
  printf("RECORD INSERTED: %d\n", idInsert);
}

static void *addRecord(List *list, int newID) 
{
  //Allocate memory for the node
  Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node)); 

  //Add in data
  new->id = newID; 

  new->prev = list->last;
  new->next = NULL;

  list->last = new;

  // if list is empty
  if(!list->head)
  {
    list->head = new;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }

  Node **next_p = &list->head;
  while (*next_p) {
    next_p = &(*next_p)->next;
  }
  *next_p = new;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void printReverse(List *list) {
    Node **tail = &list->last;
    printf("LIST IN REVERSE ORDER:\n");

    //Traversing until tail end of linked list
    while (*tail) {
        printf("Item ID: %d\n", (*tail)->id);
        tail = &(*tail)->prev;
    }
}

void delete(int key, List *list)
{
  //Check if ID exists in list
  if (search(list, key) == false) {
    printf("Invalid command\n");
  } else {
    printf("RECORD DELETED: %d\n", key);
  }

  //If linked list is empty (base case)
  Node **current = &list->head;

  //current points to the pointer pointing towards the current node
  //For the first iteration, it is the address of the head pointer
  while (*current && key != (*current)->id) {
    current = &(*current)->next;
  }

  (*current)->next->prev = (*current)->prev;

  if (*current) {
    Node *temp = *current;
    *current = (*current)->next;
    free(temp);
  }

}

bool search(List *list, int x)
{
  Node *current = list->head; //Initialize current node
  while (current != NULL) {
    if (current->id == x) {
      return true;
    }
    current = current->next;
  }
  return false;
}
```

My desired results would be:

```
RECORD INSERTED: 15
RECORD DELETED: 7
RECORD DELETED: 1
RECORD DELETED: 4
RECORD DELETED: 2
RECORD DELETED: 5
Invalid command
LIST IN REVERSE ORDER: 
Item ID: 15
Item ID: 3
```

instead of the segmentation fault. How can I improve the code in my delete method so I do not receive this error, and why is it present currently?

Comment: If you try to delete the last node, then node->next->prev is invalid and crashed -->  next is NULL, and you can't do NULL->prev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you print out `Invalid Command`, what does your code do?  It continues execution within the function, eventually reaching the `(*current)->next->prev = (*current)->prev;` line which will result in the segfault because `*current` will be NULL.

This exposes three issues.  The first is that you're effectively searching for `key` twice:  once to see if it is in the list, then a second time to locate the place in the list where that node is so it can be removed.  These should be combined so only one search needs to be made.  One way to do this is have `find` return an appropriate pointer so you can find and delete the node.  Another would be to just do the search manually (not calling `find`) and reporting the error if you don't find `key`.

The second issue is the missing `return` after printing `Invalid Command`, although implementing the previous suggestion can avoid this problem.

The third issue is that the assignment to `(*current)->next->prev` should be within the following `if (*current)` to avoid dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up using the `return` statement, and now my program works perfectly.